# Is it possible to deploy delegated custom object adminstration via API / Changeset

Tags: metadata-api, delegated-admin

A few documents list delegated adminstration as something that cannot be retrieved or deployed via metadata API, including the '[unsupported metadata types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm)' doc

However, the [metadata api docs list delegateGroup as a covered object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_delegategroup.htm), and I was able to successfully retrieve an existing Delegated Adminstration Group via workbench

I modified the xml to add an additional custom object, and packaged it and deployed it via workbench, but the delegated group itself has not been modified.

And in the success info, I'm just seeing one component (package.xml), and not my delegatedGroup component.

Not sure if its an issue w the package.xml file, or maybe b/c i'm dealing w a managed object, or maybe i need to include the object in the package?

Package xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Sage_Master_Admins</members>
        <name>DelegateGroup</name>
    </types>
    <version>44.0</version>
</Package>
```

And the Sage_Master_Admins.delegateGroup file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DelegateGroup xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customObjects>fHCM2__Absence__c</customObjects>
    <label>Sage Master Admins</label>
    <loginAccess>false</loginAccess>
</DelegateGroup>
```

Note that the retrieve brings back the object names without the namespace prefix. I have tried deploying with and without the namespace prefix, and both have been equally unsuccessful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When including an object in the .delegateGroup XML remove the suffix "__c" from the object name. The namespace should be included.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DelegateGroup xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customObjects>fHCM2__Absence</customObjects>
    <label>Sage Master Admins</label>
    <loginAccess>false</loginAccess>
</DelegateGroup>
```

The metadata api supports all aspects of "Delegated Administration", except adding Users as "Delegated Admins"